# Ziya Linking a Bar to a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, graphing

I am working on a project that uses Ziya and updating to rails 3, however, I need to be able to make each bar on a column chart link to another URL.  The problem is that I can't find any documentation on it.  Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See helpsheets.co](https://www.helpsheets.co/questions/1-how-do-i-create-a-link-on-a-barchart-with-ziya) for the answer to this question.